# Systemd configuration to run script as service

Tags: sh, systemd, systemctl

If I run `/home/pi/update.sh` everything works fine;
If I run it via systemd service, script will not be executed.

Content of script:

```
/home/pi/update.sh

#!/bin/sh
script='/opt/server/htdocs/due.py'
/usr/bin/python $script &
```

Here you are Systemd config: Is there any mistake within code below?

```
/lib/systemd/system/httpdevice.service
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/httpdevice.service

    [Unit]
    Description=httpdevice-service

    [Service]
    Type=simple
    User=pi
    ExecStart=/home/pi/update.sh

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here status:

```
sudo systemctl status httpdevice.service

● httpdevice.service - httpdevice
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/httpdevice.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2018-04-27 18:01:52 CEST; 17min ago
  Process: 402 ExecStart=/home/pi/update.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 402 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 27 18:01:51 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting httpdevice...
Apr 27 18:01:51 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started httpdevice.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is `Type=simple`. Your service definitely started, and then quit. However, you're probably misled by the child Python process. Child processes are not part of a "simple" service.

It might be simpler to just have `ExecStart=/opt/bin/python opt/server/htdocs/due.py` and skip the whole script.